# How can I replace only the cheater vent portion?

Tags: plumbing, shower

I am a bit new to this so forgive me if I am not naming the parts correctly.

Ive had a bad sewer smell so I figured out it was the air admittance valve. I bought the correct replacement part to thread on only to find out it was cemented on. I can't get the slip joint nut (if thats what its called) off because of the cement. Is the part below that nut a tailpiece? And if it is, is that not just 1 1/2 inch ABS pipe? Instead of replacing the entire thing can I cut a portion of that tailpiece off? [image]

Answer (score 2):

The **AAV** unscrews. That's **not** a nut, it's a **female threaded adapter** and it's glued to the pipe, as it should be. It's not a slip fit, it's pipe threads.

It's not a tailpiece, it's drain pipe. *And those two are not the same.*

Use two wrenches - one to hold that female adapter so you're not stressing the pipe it's attached to, and one to turn the AAV to remove it.

Being it's pipe threads, be sure to use pipe dope or teflon tape on the threads before installing the new AAV.

If it's really and truly stuck, or they actually used glue on the threads, you can cut it off and use a coupling to attach new ABS pipe and a new female threaded adapter. You should use as much pipe length as you can fit in the space where that is, so the AAV is located as high as it can be in there while still being serviceable - that should increase the time until this has to be done again, by keeping it further from drain water and contamination.

Comment: Thank you sir. I was able to get it out with the using 2 wrenches like you suggested and replaced the part. Smell has subsided drastically.